# CAML Query returning null

Tags: caml-query, caml, sharepoint-addin

I'm very new to sharepoint and have the following query on my Shared Documents. It is returning null for all three documents I have.

I'm wondering where to check in database to see if values are null or how to debug this basically. I can see where it breaks in VS but doesn't give me any clue as to where null is coming from.

code:

```
//ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
var context = null;
var web = null;
var currentUser = null;
var collListItems = null;
var username = null;
var loginname = null;
var isgettinglist = false;
function DisplayUser() {
    isgettinglist = false;
    GetUserData();
}
function DisplayList() {
    isgettinglist = true;
    GetUserData();
}
function GetUserData() {
    //## Getting the context
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    //## Getting the web
    web = context.get_web();
    //## Getting the current user
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    //## Load the query
    currentUser.retrieve();
    context.load(web);
    //## Execute the query Async
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}
function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
    //## Setting the object to get the current user...again...
    var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
    //## Adding the user into a Variable
    username = userObject.get_title();
    loginname = userObject.get_loginName();
    if (isgettinglist == false) {
        alert('User name:' + username + '\n Login Name:' + loginname);
    }
    if (isgettinglist == true) {
        //## Getting the results from the list
        GetListByName();
    }
}
function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
function SayHello() {
    alert('Hello Word');
}

function GetListByName() {

    //## Get the context again
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    //## Get the list
    var list = context.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('Shared Documents');
    //## Builds a CAMEL querty to return items
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Author"/><Value Type="User">' + username + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Title"/><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/></ViewFields></View>');
    //## Geting the items
    this.collListItems = list.getItems(query);
    context.load(collListItems);
    //## Execute the query Async
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.mySuccessFunction),                   
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.myFailFunction));
}

function mySuccessFunction() {
    // Do something useful like loop through your returned list items and output them somewhere
    // create an enumerator to loop through the list with 
    var listItemEnumerator = this.collListItems.getEnumerator();
    var strHtml = "RESULTS:";
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        strHtml += oListItem.get_item('Title');
    }
    alert(strHtml);
}
function myFailFunction() { alert('Request fail'); }
```

Comment: can you let us know how you solved this problem? I am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm these points before running CAML query,

-> Are you calling GetListByName function after loading SP.js? If not use this statement to call your function after SP.js was loaded.

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourfunction, "SP.js");

-> Are you passing username as full name? 
For eg: If username is Arun Balaji, you should pass whole name as it is. Here Arun is First name and Balaji is Last name.

Comment: I can see in -> Team Site  Shared Documents  Document Library Settings that there is a column named 'Title'. I am calling the function after SP.js

Comment: You can try executing the CAML query without where condition. This is to verify whether problem exists in existing CAML query or anything else. You can also try using alert before executing the query to check list loaded or not.

Comment: Does CAML query works fine? What changes you made?

Comment: I couldnt get it to work. It appears the username is fine as to whats in the shared documents table but it just returns null for each document and not the actual name or title. your advice was welcome though. I'll have to work this one out on my own I think

Comment: Do you have CAML Query Builder? You can verify your query on that. Else try getting all values from Shared Document.

Comment: I've hear about this CAML Query Builder but I'm using a VM on cloudshare at the moment. where would I find this on the computer. is it a program or its part of something? thanks for help

Comment: It is a separate program that will be installed when SharePoint is installed. You can see that in this location. Start -> All Programs -> U2U -> CAML Builder.

Answer (score 0):

In your example I fail to see where do you collect USERNAME. One option could be (let CAML do the job for you by retrieving Current User )

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Author' />
        <Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

or

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Author'/>
        <Value Type='Text'>Lastname, Firstname</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: I updated with more of the code